# How can I fix TF2 segfaulting running on Linux?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, linux

I run Steam natively on Linux. I installed *Team Fortress 2*, and when I try to start it, I get the normal "Preparing to launch Team Fortress 2" dialog. Then the screen goes black for about 15 seconds. Then it crashes. Log:

```
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1353457964_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
[1127/165746:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
GLError: 1282
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
Adding license for package 7932
Adding license for package 8187
Adding license for package 8538
Adding license for package 0
roaming config store loaded successfully - 1319 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
ExecCommandLine: "/home/____/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/games"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/games"
Generating new string page texture 75: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1.36 MB
Generating new string page texture 76: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.49 MB
Generating new string page texture 77: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131.07 KB
Generating new string page texture 78: 64x256, total string texture memory is 1.56 MB
Generating new string page texture 79: 8x256, total string texture memory is 1.56 MB
Generating new string page texture 80: 32x256, total string texture memory is 1.60 MB
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

(steam:9339): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so


(steam:9339): Gtk-WARNING **: A floating object was finalized. This means that someone
called g_object_unref() on an object that had only a floating
reference; the initial floating reference is not owned by anyone
and must be removed with g_object_ref_sink().
Generating new string page texture 84: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.73 MB
Generating new string page texture 85: 512x256, total string texture memory is 2.25 MB
Generating new string page texture 93: 384x256, total string texture memory is 2.65 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1.0)
System startup time: 17.29 seconds
Game update: AppID 440 "Team Fortress 2", ProcID 9397, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object 'gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
saving roaming config store to 'sharedconfig.vdf'
roaming config store 2 saved successfully
SDL video target is 'x11'
SDL video target is 'x11'
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_fence.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_fence.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_sync.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers2.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_bindable_uniform.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_flush_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_map_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_occlusion_query.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_texture_range.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_client_storage.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_framebuffer_object.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_GREMEDY_string_marker.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_debug_output.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_direct_state_access.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_bindless_texture.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_AMD_pinned_memory.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ATI_meminfo.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear.
GL_NV_bindless_texture: DISABLED
GL_AMD_pinned_memory: DISABLED
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode: AVAILABLE
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(20121120153152_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
[1127/165819:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Using breakpad crash handler
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 440
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(440)/version(5126_client)
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198067023147 [API loaded yes]
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Setting Steam ID:  76561198067023147
ConVarRef m_rawinput doesn't point to an existing ConVar
GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info: UNAVAILABLE
GL_ATI_meminfo: AVAILABLE
GL_ATI_meminfo: GL_TEXTURE_FREE_MEMORY_ATI: Total Free: 275489, Largest Avail: 131216, Total Aux: 1723617, Largest Aux Avail: 4096
GL_MAX_SAMPLES_EXT: 8
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
CShaderDeviceMgrBase::GetRecommendedConfigurationInfo: CPU speed: 1500 MHz, Processor: AuthenticAMD
GlobalMemoryStatus: 4294967295
CShaderDeviceMgrBase::GetRecommendedConfigurationInfo: CPU speed: 1500 MHz, Processor: AuthenticAMD
GlobalMemoryStatus: 4294967295
[1127/165821:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(646)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
IDirect3DDevice9::Create: BackBufWidth: 1366, BackBufHeight: 768, D3DFMT: 3, BackBufCount: 1, MultisampleType: 0, MultisampleQuality: 0
/home/____/Steam/SteamApps/pbfy00/Team Fortress 2/hl2.sh: line 72:  9404 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${GAME_DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} "$@"
Game removed: AppID 440 "Team Fortress 2", ProcID 9404 
saving roaming config store to 'sharedconfig.vdf'
roaming config store 2 saved successfully
```

Is there anyone who knows what is happening or how to fix it?
Edit: The CrashID is `bp-f7f07eb8-7f54-46a6-bd18-c97352121223`

Comment: Is this through Wine or some other compatibility layer? Or is this an actual native Linux Steam client?

Comment: This is the native Linux Steam client

Comment: Did you try asking on the official forums? Feedbacks like this are the reason an open beta exists.

Comment: It isn't an open beta, and I'm not officially in it

Comment: I am invited to the beta and have the same problem, I am going to file a ticket in the Steam support website. I hope to come back with news!

Comment: It looks like you might be missing dependencies. Does the file '/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so' exist? If not, does 'find / -name libappmenu.so' find any files? I'm betting that the error is related to the initial "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"" message.

Comment: It does not exist, but I get that with everything gtk2, and this is the only thing that segfaults. Also, it exists as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so`
edit: do you know about the `locate` command? it uses a database of files and is much faster than find

Comment: Hi @pbfy0 - Did you ever solve this? If so and you remember what fixed it, you should add an answer. If not and it's still happening I suggest raising a ticket with Steam Support.

Answer (score 1):

It seems many game files are missing from your game.  
Validate your game files through Properties->Local Files->"Verify integrity of files..."